# How to set current year in Django Forms?

Tags: django, time, django-forms

I have a bit trouble with django-from. I would want to get Integer field from 1960 to current year.

In *forms.py* I have:

```
year = forms.IntegerField(label='year', min_value=1960, max_value=datetime.now().year)
```

And it works!

```
<input id="id_year" max="2016" min="1960" name="year" type="number">
```

**But** if I replace *datetime.now().**year*** on *datetime.now().**second***, the problem becomes evident

The value of the field filled at server startup (now I use django development server)

```
February 19, 2016 - 18:54:05
Djangoversion 1.9.1, using settings Test.settings
Starting development server at http://localhost:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And now in the HTML template I get

```
<input id="id_year" max="5" min="1960" name="year" type="number">
```

**BUT** real time is *18:54:18*.

The question: What should I do, to make changing the year automatically?

Comment: I really don't get what you trying to do. What's your goal? To show current year, right? Why do you change it to `datetime.now().second` then?

Comment: What do you expect when `datetime.now().second` is used ? It is showing `max=5` which is probably the 5th second.

Comment: I  want to change the year automatically. The example with seconds show that year (also as seconds) won't change with server time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you're concerned that the value is only changed when the server starts up, you could remedy this by setting the value in the init method of the form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['year'].max_value = datetime.now().year
```